# Android: creating alert dialog when back button is pressed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, back-button

I have added the below code so if back button is pressed in the main activity it shows a alert dialog with two buttons to make a final decision...but sometimes when i click on *YES* (a positive button to finish the activity) the same activity shown again instead of finishing the activity, i want  to know whether there is any mistake in my code...

MainActivity.java

```
public void onBackPressed() {

        //super.onBackPressed();
        Log.d("back button", "back button pressed");
        AlertDialog.Builder ad1=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ad1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit? ");
        ad1.setCancelable(false);


        ad1.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {             
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {   


            }
        });

        ad1.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {   
                finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert=ad1.create();
        alert.show();   

            }
```

MainActivity.java complete code

```
package com.vibrator;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnCheckedChangeListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener{

    ToggleButton tbutton;
    Vibrator v;
    int i=400,j=50;
    int k,l;
    TextView txt;
    SeekBar sb;
    TextView txt1;
    SeekBar sb1;
    Spinner spinner1;
    Button btn;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#336699")));

        //Log.e("values","i value at oncreate "+i);
        //Log.e("values","i value at oncreate  "+j);
        //creating instance for vibrator
         v=(Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);        
         //checking if the device has vibrator or not        
        if(v!=null){

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }
        else {
            setContentView(R.layout.secound);
        }
            //Log.e("vibrate", "setcontentview");


        //creating instance of toggle buttton and setting listener
        tbutton=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tb1);
        tbutton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


        //creating instance and setting onclicklistener for the button
        /*btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);*/

        sb=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt12);
        sb1=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar1);
        txt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt11);


        sb1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);       
        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);




    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        //Log.d("real status", ""+arg1);
        //if vibrator is ON
        if(arg1)
        {
            Log.e("vibrate", "true vibrate");

            // Start without a delay
            // Vibrate for 100 j milliseconds
            // Sleep for 1000  (i) milliseconds 
            Log.e("values","i value "+i);
            Log.e("values","i value "+j);
            long pattern[] = {0, j, i};
            // The '0' here means to repeat indefinitely
            // '-1' would play the vibration once                       
            v.vibrate(pattern, 0);          
        }

        else {

            Log.e("vibrate", "false no v");
            //Toast.makeText(this,"status: "+arg1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            v.cancel();         
        }       
    }


    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar s, int v, boolean b) {

        //switch statement to update values of seekbars
                switch (s.getId()) {
                case R.id.seekbar:
                    k=v;
                    txt.setText("Vibrator OFF time: "+k);
                    //Log.e("values","seekbar value "+k);
                    break;

                case R.id.seekbar1:
                    l=v;
                    txt1.setText("Vibrator ON time: "+l);
                    //Log.e("values","seekbar1 value "+l);
                    break;

                }   
        //seekbarchanged method implementation
        if (tbutton.isChecked()) {
            Log.e("values","yes tbutton is checked");   
        tbutton.setChecked(false);
        switch (s.getId()) {
        case R.id.seekbar:
            i=k;            
            //Log.e("true", "seekbar tbutton checked "+i);
            break;

        case R.id.seekbar1:
            j=l;
            //Log.e("true", "seekbar1 tbutton checked "+j);
            break;      
        }       
        Log.e("true", "set true");
        tbutton.setChecked(true);

    }       
        else{
            //Toast.makeText(this,"Set ON to customize", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            ad.setTitle("Instruction");
            ad.setMessage("Set the button ON to customize");
            ad.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {               
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {                   
                }
            });
            ad.show();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {        
    }
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {     
    }


    @Override


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflate= getMenuInflater();
        inflate.inflate(R.menu.menu_v, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_setting:     
            break;

        case R.id.about:
            //Toast.makeText(this, "about clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            ad.setTitle("About");
            ad.setMessage("This app is developed by Rajesh Uragonda");
            ad.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {               
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {                   
                }
            });
            ad.show();          
            break;  

        case R.id.settings:
            //Toast.makeText(this, "settings clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder ad2=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            ad2.setTitle("Settings");
            ad2.setMessage("Your settings here");
            ad2.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {              
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {                   
                }
            });
            ad2.show(); 
            break;
        case R.id.help:
            //Toast.makeText(this, "help clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder ad1=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            ad1.setTitle("Help");
            ad1.setMessage(R.string.alerthelp);
            ad1.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {              
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {                   
                }
            });
            ad1.show();


            break;



        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPause();
        if (tbutton.isChecked()) {
            tbutton.setChecked(false);
            Log.d("onpause", "onpause mainactivity tbutton");
        }
        Log.d("onpause", "onpause mainactivity");

    }


    //responds to the button at top used as navigation to next activity
    public void btn(View v){
        //Button btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustomPatterns.class);
        startActivity(i);
        }

    //when back button pressed it goes directly to home
    public void onBackPressed() {

        //super.onBackPressed();
        Log.d("back button", "back button pressed");
        AlertDialog.Builder ad1=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ad1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit? ");
        ad1.setCancelable(false);


        ad1.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {             
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {   


            }
        });

        ad1.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {   

                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert=ad1.create();
        alert.show();   

                }

            }
```

Comment: In the positive response, using `super.onBackPressed()` should be sufficient. Instead of `finish()'.

Comment: @TronicZomB actually super.onBackPressed calls just finish()

Comment: @blackbelt Good to know. Thanks. Is that all that `super.onBackPressed()` does?

Comment: how many times did you started the activity without finish it?

Comment: also, do you have fragments? Do you add those on the backstack? What version of android are you experiencing this issue?

Comment: Android version 2.3, my app has only two activities i do not have any fragments. The above code is working fine when I do not navigate to another activity...but when i navigate to other activity and press back button in MainActivity.java it is displaying the same activity instead of finishing the activity...

Answer (score 1):

use this code in your activity

```
public void onBackPressed() {
  AlertDialog diaBox = AskOption();
  diaBox.show();
}

private AlertDialog AskOption()
 {
    AlertDialog myQuittingDialogBox =new AlertDialog.Builder(this) 
        .setTitle("Exit") 
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?") 

        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) { 
            finish();
            }   
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        })
        .create();
        return myQuittingDialogBox;

    }
```

Comment: the same activity is displayed again when i press positive button as if we pressed negative button....but sometimes it is working

Comment: finish(); should finish your activity. never mind , can u please try to press back button more than one time and tell me what happens it will help me to help you

Comment: posted please have a look

Comment: Is your activity a launcher activity

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to pass a activity context to the dialog in its constructor and finishing it using context.finish().

```
dismiss();//dismiss dialog first
context.finish();//then finish the hosting activity
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an alertdialog onclick of MenuItem...

just go through below code..
Thanks

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{           
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menu_cgoal:
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final EditText input = new EditText(Myclass.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        input.setLayoutParams(lp);
        //input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        AlertDialog.Builder ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(Myclass.this);
        ad.setView(input);
        ad.setTitle("Create goal...");
        ad.setMessage("Are you sure you want to add this goal?");

        ad.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {               
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) { 
                String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        ad.show();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

not just `finish()`. use `MainActivity.this.finish();`

Comment: It is working fine when we do not navigate to another activities...but when we navigate to other activities and press back button in MainActivity.java it is displaying the same activity instead of finishing the activity...

Comment: i think it could be problem with context.. use the Activity context and try